# In Java, how can I load classes without knowing the name ahead of time?

Tags: java, class, dynamic, syntax, dynamic-class-loaders

I have a directory that looks like this:

```
src
|
|__ProblemTester.java
|
|__problems
   |
   |__AbstractProblem.java
   |
   |__Problem1.java
   |
   |__Problem2.java
   |
   |__Problem3.java
```

All of the classes extend `AbstractProblem`. I want to have a function that takes the input `int n` and returns an instance of `ProblemN.java` (as part of a testing framework). Is this possible?

My code so far: (very rough)

```
class ProblemTester {

    Class<? extends AbstractProblem> problem;

    ProblemTest(int number) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {
            problem = Class.forName("problems.Problem" + number);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Problem %d not found.", number));
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this throws the error `Incompatible types. Required: Class<? extends AbstractProblem>. Found: Class<capture <?>>.`

How can I fix this? Is there an existing framework for something like this? I've used gradle in the past but I don't think it loads classes automatically like I'd like this function to do. Thanks.

Comment: what does *Class.forName("problems.Problem" + number);* evaluate to for number=1? Your package structure doesn't reflect `Capture<>` anywhere. And you shall share ProblemN models as well

Comment: I meant for it to evaluate to "problems.Problem1". I haven't heard of Capture<>, I'll look it up. What do you mean by 'share ProblemN models'?

Comment: Definition of Problem1,2,3 is what I meant.

Comment: They're fairly simple test cases. They have local variables like testInputOne and expectedResultOne. I'm planning to make quite a few similar classes so I'd rather have one big test class than a dozen smaller ones.

Comment: Wasn't asking about their attributes but class definition, do they all extend `AbstractProblem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but as far as I know Generics were not meant to be used as meta-types (for classes), so what you can do is, declare your problem as:

```
AbstractProblem problem;
```

and then:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("Problem" + number);
problem = (AbstractProblem) clazz.newInstance();
```